# Which fields are in my ElasticSearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I ran a conversion program, [catmandu](https://github.com/LibreCat/Catmandu), and sent the results to elasticsearch. I'm new to elasticsearch. Do you know how I could find something similar to '.schema' for sqlite3 in elasticsearch? I'd like to know what fields are in there.

After searching around this morning I was unable to find something that would tell me the fields if I did not know them ahead of time.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the mapping API to get current mapping for an index. This will show you all of the fields that have been indexed:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/{yourIndex}/_mapping"
```